# include local on map with firebase swift - error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, maps

I am encountering great difficulties in putting an integrated map based on firebase in my project, I am looking for expert knowledge to help me, even though I build run correctly at the time of running the system for, my code below:

Thanks

```
@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let locationsRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "locations")

    locationsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            guard let locationData = item as? DataSnapshot else { continue }
            var locationValue = locationData.value as! [String: Any]
            var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

            if let lat = locationValue["lat"] as? String {
                let lng = Double(locationValue["lng"] as! String)!
                location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lat)!, longitude: lng)
            }  else {
                let lat = locationValue["lat"] as! Double
                let lng = locationValue["lng"] as! Double
                location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
            }

            func addAnnotations(coords: [CLLocation]){
                for coord in coords{
                    let CLLCoordType = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coord.coordinate.latitude,
                                                              longitude: coord.coordinate.longitude);
                    let anno = MKPointAnnotation();
                    anno.coordinate = CLLCoordType;
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(anno);
                }

            }  
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: what is the issue ???

Comment: What is problem  you are facing ?

Comment: Looks like you didn't call `addAnnotations` method from anywhere so it is not been added .

Comment: Sorry, there's the problem accessing: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x1095b2208) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1095b31a8).
2018-02-13 10:17:26.303387-0200 MultipleTableviewCellFirebase[52976:1652622] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x1095b2208) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1095b31a8).

Comment: It is clear error you are trying to use Number value as Dictionary  possibly  at . location -> `locationData.value as! [String: Any]` check it

Comment: yes, I noticed that the error is at the time of the search of the coordinates in the firebase, since the values ​​are numerical. I'm really looking for the solution and I do not think so. would you have any tips to solve the problem? Thank you so much, greetings from Brazil.

Comment: any suggestion?